# Git branching strategies for CI/CD on Azure Devops 2019

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, git-branch, continuous-deployment

I am setting a CI/CD pipeline on Azure devops.
[image]

This one gets executed when a Build for the master branch is completed.

I was asked to set the stages of the image above, which description is the next one:

1. Development, QA and Production : Publish the build artifacts on a server (each one).
2. Testing: Execute some automated test with katalon studio.

My problem is that, when I create a Development branch this pipeline cannot be executed for the build, because the pipeline is just executed when I commit to the master branch, then I create another CI/CD pipeline for Development branch, remove Development stage from Master CI/CD pipeline and incorporate it in this new pipeline.

My question is... is that correct ? , what´s the best estrategy for git branching when you have this kind of pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that, when I create a Development branch this pipeline
>   cannot be executed for the build, because the pipeline is just
>   executed when I commit to the master branch, then I create another
>   CI/CD pipeline for Development branch

For this issue, you don't need to do that. You only need to add the Development branch to the Branch filters of Continuous Integration in build Triggers.
[image]

Then add the Development branch to the Build branch filters of the Continuous deployment trigger.

[image]

After this setting, when you commit to development branch, build and release pipeline will also be triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know the existance of that feature.